# Getting SSMS database restore run time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, restore

Is there a way, in t-sql (SQL Server specifically), to find out how long a database took to restore?
I'm able to find the backup database start\end time, but I am unable to find the same for the restore time.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this script to see an estimated completion time for a restore running.

```
SELECT session_id, command, t.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) t
WHERE er.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```

Comment: I already have elaborate code like that that runs DURING the restore.  I'm looking for code that will show how long a restore took, for example, 2 or 3 days ago.  Or over the course of a week.

Comment: This link may help you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101291/history-of-database-restore-completion-times